# If statement logic help needed

Tags: android, android-studio, calculator

I am creating a calculator using android studio.
I don't want to append operators in the edittext if it is empty and i have implemented the same using **setOnclicklistner();** but  it doesn't seem to work the intended way. The operators get appended even if the edittext is empty(only with +,- and % as i have used **android:xml** for multiply).I am curious to know why it is happening. Here are my files

**MyActivity.java**

```
package com.example.meenakshi.calculator;


import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText text;
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button10).setOnClickListener(this);
   //findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
    //findViewById(R.id.button15).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button16).setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v){
    btn = (Button)v;
    if(text.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
        if(btn.getText().toString() != "+" && btn.getText().toString()!= "-" &&btn.getText().toString()!= "%" /*&& btn.getText().toString()!= "*"*/  )
           text.append(btn.getText());
    }else{
        text.append(btn.getText());
    }
}
public void mul(View view){
    btn = (Button)view;
    if(text.getText().toString().trim().length()!= 0)
        text.append(btn.getText());
}
public void calculate(View view){

       Interpreter in = new Interpreter();
       if(text.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
           try {
              text.setText("="+in.eval(text.getText().toString()).toString());
          } catch (EvalError e) {
               text.setText(e.getErrorText());
          }
      }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.meenakshi.calculator.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_pressed"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="@string/buttond_text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button4_text"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "@string/button2_text"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:onClick="press2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button3_text"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonmul_text"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:onClick="mul" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button7_text"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button5_text"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button6_text"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button8_text"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonm_text"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button._text"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button0_text"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button9_text"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttone_text"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="calculate" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonp_text"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3" />
</GridLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `String. equals` instead of `==` for comparing String values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always compare `String`s like this.

```
btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("+");
```